# Connection and CRUD operation over kundera Cassandra and Play framework

Tags: playframework-2.0, cassandra, crud, kundera

I am trying to connect Cassandra 1.1.9 over Kundera with Play 2.0 framework. I tried the example *Getting-Started-in-5-minutes* on GitHub. But I got this exception:

`[PersistenceLoaderException: com.impetus.kundera.utils.InvalidConfigurationException: Duplicate persistence-units for name: cassandra_pu. verify your persistence.xml file]`

I just added *kundera-cassandra-2.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar* to project build path. Should I add anything to application.conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is PlayOrm for cassandra with the playframework which has it's own in-memory nosql which is usually how playframework is used in development for speed of coding and no server restarts ;) (and it keeps that data as you change your code just like the in-memory RDBMS options give you.  There is also a 1.2.x playframework plugin too since the 1.2.x version is way way more productive if you are in java(in scala, it is probably just as slow to develop in because of the slowness of the scala compiler....I am hoping they get that faster and faster as I did love scala).

Dean

Comment: Thanks Dean, Then please share with us your startup code as you mentioned about at [link](http://www.mail-archive.com/user@cassandra.apache.org/msg25156.html).

Comment: heh, there's an old post.  There is ALOT more documentation these dadys and you can find it on steps 5 and 6 here https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/wiki

Answer (score 0):

AFA Kundera is concerned i have replied another thread of yours for this error. Request you to join at http://groups.google.com/group/kundera-discuss/subscribe for quick support on such errors.

-Vivek